# Why does a \catcode-changed underscore work in math mode also without \mathcode set to "8000?

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex, catcodes, mathcode

Something is puzzling me... consider

```
%\begingroup
%\catcode`\_=13
%\gdef_{\sb}
%\endgroup

\catcode`\_=11
\def\foo_bar{Foo bar}

\foo_bar\ $a_b$
\bye
```

[image]

Uncommenting the commented code yields

[image]

(One can wrap this in a LaTeX file, the result is the same.)
What is puzzling me is that I haven't set `` \mathcode`\_="8000 `` so I would have expected the first result also with the uncommented code.

What am I missing?

Comment: ``\showthe\mathcode`\_``

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, it came to me twelve seconds after I posted the question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*you* have not set `\mathcode="8000` but someone called Knuth has...

```
\mathcode`\_="8000 % \_
```

plain.tex line 106

Comment: Yep, it came to me twelve seconds after I posted the question... time to go to bed.

Comment: @campa actually it's an interesting question, as it's perhaps not immediately obvious that mathcode"8000 is "harmless" when `_` has its normal subscript meaning, and is just sitting there waiting for someone to make a catcode 11 or 12 `_`

Comment: and plain.tex line 742 says more.

Comment: With hindsight I think what was actually puzzling me is that the effect of mathcode 8000 works only for characters with catcode 11 or 12. But I found this oiece of info only here and in tex for the impatient, but not the texbook.

Comment: @campa as always with the texbook the trick is to find the information elsewhere then go back and find it eventually somewhere in the texbook: `\TeX\ looks at the mathcode only when it is typesetting a character whose
catcode is 11~(letter) or 12~(other), or when it encounters a character that
is given explicitly as ^|\char|\<number>.`

Comment: note that that is not a special feature about mathcode"8000, all mathcodes are ignored for catcodes other than 11 or 12 @campa

Comment: And I've read that page three times yesterday... shame on me...

Comment: @campa don't _read_ it, you just have `texbook.tex` in an emacs buffer and search for `mathcode` (did I mention I use emacs)